# "Тот же" or "такой же"

Tags: грамматика

How do I say I have the same book? Is it:
У меня есть такая же or та же книга. 
What's the difference between the 2 variants?

Comment: the simplest way to remember is: "такой же"="same as", "тот же"="the same"

Answer (score 8):

**Тот же (самый)** points to one object (that very book).
**Такой же** points to different but identical objects (the same/the identical book).

> Этот дом такой же, как и тот. (we are speaking about two houses)
>
> Это тот же самый дом. (one house is described.)

Answer (score 0):

An object of the same quality is 'the same object'.

***У меня чёрная рубаха, и у тебя такая же.***

***Эта станция удобная, и та такая же.***

***Борщ холодный, и чай такой же.***

The examples have the obvious (that is, spoken in phrases) qualities of the objects as topics.

An object to which to or more speakers refer is 'the very object':

***У меня чёрная рубаха, а у тебя - та же.***

***Эта станция удобная, а та - та же.***

***Борщ холодный, а чай - тот же.***

In the examples given, the qualities of the objects are opposite to those spoken out in the beginning of the phrases. It is also implied that there is no change in quality of the objects mentioned in the second parts of phrases, or that they are not evident.

You can also put the adjectives from the first group of examples (similar qualities) into the second structure group and the phrases still would have the same meaning, but you cannot do it the other way round (that is, the adjectives are interchangeable in the second group only).

Hence, ***У меня есть такая же книга.*** = I have a book of the same (evident) qualities.

***У меня есть та же книга.*** = I have the same book as you have mentioned (and the book could be non-visible at the moment of speech).